# How to get total size of free memory in C in linux?

Tags: c, linux, memory

In java it's simply:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
```

How to do it in C?

Comment: Just as an FYI, that's not really free memory. That's how much memory is available to your process from the JVM which ... isn't the same thing.

Comment: Its not even that. ;) its how much is left in the shared heap without having to perform a GC. Java allocates chunks of memory called TLAB (Thread Local Allocation Buffers) so each thread could have plenty of memory, the free memory is 0 and yet no GC is performed. You can allocate direct memory and memory map files without this appearing to change. After a GC is performed the `freeMemory` suddenly increases.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the virtual memory limit for a process under linux using [getrlimit()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit) with the RLIMIT_AS parameter.

Comment: To calculate `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`, you still need to know how much memory the process has consumed,right?

Comment: AFAIK currently used virtual memory is pretty hard to pin down with shared libs and such.  If it is anywhere it is in /proc.  Try /proc/[pid]/smaps.and/or /proc/[pid]/status.

Answer (score 3):

Your comments seem to indicate what you really want to know is the most memory that `malloc` can allocate in a single block.  That would approximately the maximum allowed VM size minus the current VM size.  The following code returns that:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t get_total_free_mem()
{
    uint64_t vm_size = 0;
    FILE *statm = fopen("/proc/self/statm", "r");
    if (!statm)
        return 0;
    if (fscanf("%ld", &vm_size) != 1)
    {
        flcose(statm);
        return 0;
    }
    vm_size = (vm_size + 1) * 1024;

    rlimit lim;
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &lim) != 0)
        return 0;
    if (lim.rlim_cur <= vm_size)
        return 0;
    if (lim.rlim_cur >= 0xC000000000000000ull) // most systems cannot address more than 48 bits
        lim.rlim_cur  = 0xBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFull;
    return lim.rlim_cur - vm_size;
}
```

The only exception is that in some cases `getrlimit` could return `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` however most 64-bit systems cannot address more than 48 bits of address to be used, no matter what.  I've accounted for that, but there may be some other edge cases I have missed.  For example, 32-bit applications cannot typically allocate more than 3GB of memory, though that depends on how the kernel was built.

The real answer here is why you would want to do this.  Usually the maximum amount that malloc can allocate is vastly larger than the amount the system can actually handle.  When you call malloc the system will happily allocate any amount you ask for (up to the AS limit which is usually ulimited) even if no pnhysical or swap space is available.  Until your program tries write to the memory (including writing 0s) with the memory is not actually allocated from physical memory or swap.  When you do write to it, that's when the system will work on finding out where to get the memory from, and thats when you might run into problems.

Your best bet is to use one of the other answers that tells you how much physical memory is available, and never allocate more than that.  Usually less, as you will want to leave some physical memory available for other processes and the kernel itself.

Comment: Why `-1` and `* 1024` in the last line?

Comment: The 1024 is because statm is in kB and not bytes, the -1 to allow a "fudge factor" since statm is not accurate to the byte.  (*I moved this calculation around because it was wrong originally because getrlimit does return bytes, not kB.)

Comment: I tried, but it returns ridiculous result like `-4611686018428357633`

Comment: @Je Rog: you're printing it out wrong, it returns an unsigned 64-bit number (thus if you see a negative you did it wrong).  If you're using printf, you want to print it with: %llu ,  It's going to return some very large numbers, in the many many GB.  That's not wrong, malloc will allow that.  It's a bad idea to allocate that though, that's what we've been trying to tell you.

Comment: Yup, it's extremely large, `13835058055281193983` in my case... Is this number normal?